# c++ class constructor with reference to a structure

Tags: c++, reference, constructor, initialization

I have a class Printer with

```
class Printer{
     struct foo{
        int i;
     };
     foo & f;
};
```

and when I call the constructor of Printer, I need to initialize f since f is a reference, but what I want is first call the constructor of foo and create a instance of it then assign it to f. The problem I have is if I call

```
Printer::Printer():f(foo(0)){ }
```

There is an error saying I cannot use reference to a temporary instance of a structure. Any way around this problem?

Thanks

Comment: You can make it a `const foo &f`, but as Oli points out, I'm not sure why you need one.

Comment: Why not add a constructor to `f`, and then you can initialize it in `Printer`'s constructor initialization list?

Comment: Thanks for answering. I totally understand a reference is not necessary, but the header file was actually given by my professor and I was asked to implement this class without changing the given code in header file (I may only add more private members). I guess I need to figure out what exactly I want to do. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

A reference doesn't make any sense in this situation.  Try the following instead:

```
class Printer{
     struct foo{
        int i;
        foo(int i_) : i(i_) {}  // Define a constructor
     };

     foo f;  // Not a reference anymore!

public:
     Printer::Printer() : f(0) {}  // Initialise f
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you actually don't want a reference to `foo` but `foo` itself.

When you call `foo(0)`, it creates a structure and returns it as a 'floating' object. You can't assign a reference to it, because no-one 'holds' it and it will be discarded as soon as the constructor exits.

So, if you would like to keep a reference to it, you would first have to store it in an actual object which would be persistent. In this case, you probably want to just keep the whole struct in the class.

Comment: Michał, don't forget though that `const` references do prolong the lifetime of the object. It's valid to have `const foo & my_foo = foo(0)`. So you're correct only in case of non-const references.

Answer (score 0):

You can make Oli's answer slightly shorter by declaring struct foo and defining f in one step:

```
class Printer{
    struct foo{
        int i;
        foo(int i_) : i(i_) {}
    } f;
public:
    Printer() : f(0) {}
};
```